# how to extract full mail address in imap php

Tags: php, cakephp, imap

i use the below code to extract header details from the mail.. i could not get the mail address in from, to and cc as mentioned below..

```
$header = explode("\n", imap_fetchheader($mbox,$msgno));
echo "<br>";
    for ($i=1; $i<count($header); $i++)
    {
        echo $header[$i] . "<br>";
    }


output:

Delivered-To: user1@examplecom 
X-WM-Delivered: user1@example.com 
Received: from ElcotPC ([127.0.0.1]) 
(envelope-sender ) 
by 127.0.0.1 with ESMTP 
for ; Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:14:19 +0530 
From: "user1" 
To: 
Cc: 
Subject: testing with attachment 
Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:14:18 +0530
```

The "from","to", "cc" field are empty without the mail address..

i want the output like this..

```
 Delivered-To: user1@examplecom 
    X-WM-Delivered: user1@example.com 
    Received: from ElcotPC ([127.0.0.1]) 
    (envelope-sender ) 
    by 127.0.0.1 with ESMTP 
    for ; Wed, 31 Jul 2013 09:14:19 +0530 
    From: "user1" <user1@example.com>
    To: <user2@example.com>
    Cc: <user1@example.com>
```

how to get the email address to "from", "to" and "cc" field?

Comment: you shoudn't echo it like that. it swallows the tags. use htmlspecialchars before you do that or some other debugging method that outputs it properly.

Comment: @mark do you know how to get attachment in the mail and save it in a folder using php?

Comment: i have seen the code from here "http://www.linuxscope.net/articles/mailAttachmentsPHP.html".. but with this code, i am not able to download..

Answer (score 2):

Update:
It's always best to use code that is readily available, so I checked if a imap-parsing function exists already. It does: `imap_rfc822_parse_headers`. [Read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-headers.php) for details, and links to all sorts of `imap_*` functions. Perhaps [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-adrlist.php) is *exactly* what you need?

---

A basic `preg_match_all` call could do the job, I think:

```
if (preg_match_all('/^\s*(From|To|Cc):[^<]*<([^>]+)\>/m',$string, $addresses)
{
    $addresses = array_merge($addresses[1], $addresses[2]);
    print_r($addresses);
}
```

Should output:

```
array (
    'From' => 'user1@example.com',
    'To' => 'user2@example.com',
    'Cc' => 'user1@example.com',
)
```

I think that's what you were looking for.
The regex explained:

- `^\s*` matches the start of the line, and zero or more whitespace chars
- `(From|To|Cc)` matches (and groups) From, To or Cc
- `:[^<]*<`: Matches (but doesn't group) the colon, and any char, except for the address delimiting `<`
- `([^>]+)`: Mathces (and groups) everything after the `<`, that isn't `>`
- `\>`: Can be left out, but matches address-delimiting `>`
- `m`: multi-line. If left out the leading `^` means *start of string*, now it means *start of line*

Notes: This expression doesn't deal with comma separated addresses or multiple addresses, and it might be usefull to call:

```
 filter_var($addresses['From'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

or use `array_map` to filter `$addresses[2]` prior to merging...

Comment: @thuk: I've updated, turns out there's no need for regex's. There are basic imap parsing functions readily available anyway

Comment: @thuk: you're welcome, I suggest you use `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`, I can't see why that shouldn't do the trick...